# Activiti and candidate groups

Tags: alfresco, activiti, aps

In APS 1.8.1, I have defined a process where each task has a candidate group.

When I login in with a user that belongs to a candidate group, I cannot see the process instance.

I have found out that when I try to access the process instances, APS executes the following query in the database:

```
select distinct RES.* , DEF.KEY_ as PROC_DEF_KEY_, DEF.NAME_ as PROC_DEF_NAME_, DEF.VERSION_ as PROC_DEF_VERSION_, DEF.DEPLOYMENT_ID_ as DEPLOYMENT_ID_
    from ACT_HI_PROCINST RES
    left outer join ACT_RE_PROCDEF DEF on RES.PROC_DEF_ID_ = DEF.ID_
        left join ACT_HI_IDENTITYLINK I_OR0 on I_OR0.PROC_INST_ID_ = RES.ID_
     WHERE  RES.TENANT_ID_ = 'tenant_1'
        and 
        (  (
              exists(select LINK.USER_ID_ from ACT_HI_IDENTITYLINK LINK where USER_ID_ = '1003' and LINK.PROC_INST_ID_ = RES.ID_)
            )
            or (
              I_OR0.TYPE_ = 'participant'
              and
              I_OR0.GROUP_ID_ IN ('1','2','2023','2013','2024','2009','2025','2026','2027','2028','2029','2007','2018','2020','2017','2015','2012','2003','2021','2019','2004','2002','2005','2030','2031','2032','2011','2006','2008','2014','2010','2016','2022','2033','2034','2035','2036','2037','1003')
            ) ) 
     order by RES.START_TIME_ desc 
    LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

This query does not return any record for two reasons:

1. In my ACT_HI_IDENTITYLINK no tasks have both the group_id_ and the proc_inst_id_ set.
2. The type of the record is "candidate" but the query is looking for "participant"

   ```
   select * fro m ACT_HI_IDENTITYLINK;
   -[ RECORD 1 ]-+----------
   id_           | 260228
   group_id_     | 
   type_         | starter
   user_id_      | 1002
   task_id_      | 
   proc_inst_id_ | 260226
   -[ RECORD 2 ]-+----------
   id_           | 260294
   group_id_     | 2006
   type_         | candidate
   user_id_      | 
   task_id_      | 260293
   proc_inst_id_ | 
   -[ RECORD 3 ]-+----------
   id_           | 260300
   group_id_     | 2009
   type_         | candidate
   user_id_      | 
   task_id_      | 260299
   proc_inst_id_ | 
   -[ RECORD 4 ]-+----------
   id_           | 262503
   group_id_     | 
   type_         | starter
   user_id_      | 1002
   task_id_      | 
   proc_inst_id_ | 262501
   -[ RECORD 5 ]-+----------
   id_           | 262569
   group_id_     | 2016
   type_         | candidate
   user_id_      | 
   task_id_      | 262568
   proc_inst_id_ | 
   -[ RECORD 6 ]-+----------
   id_           | 262575
   group_id_     | 2027
   type_         | candidate
   user_id_      | 
   task_id_      | 262574
   proc_inst_id_ |
   ```

Why the query is looking only for "participant" and why the records that have type_ = 'candidate' do not have any proc_inst_id_ set ?

**UPDATE:**
The problem with the constraint "participant" has a simple workaround: it would be enough to add the same candidate group as a participant.
See also [Feature allowing "Participant" configuration in BPM Modeler](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ACTIVITI-696)

Unfortunately this is not enough to solve the second problem. The record is still not returned because the column proc_inst_id_ is not set.

I tried to update the column manually on the "participant" record and I have verified that doing so the page is accessible and works well.

**Does anyone know why the column is not set ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution (or workaround until [ACTIVITI-696](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ACTIVITI-696) is fixed) is to add each group added as candidate to a task as a participant of the process instance.

There is a REST API that does it:

```
POST /enterprise/process-instances/{processInstanceId}/identitylinks
```

What this API does should be done by a task listener that will automatically add the candidate groups of the created task as participant of the process instance.

To add the new identity link, use in the listener the following lines:

```
ActivitiEntityEvent aee = (ActivitiEntityEvent)activitiEvent;
TaskEntity taskEntity = (TaskEntity)aee.getEntity();
List<IdentityLinkEntity> identities = taskEntity.getIdentityLinks();
if (identities != null) {
    for (IdentityLinkEntity identityLinkEntity : identities) {
        String groupId = identityLinkEntity.getGroupId();
        runtimeService.addGroupIdentityLink(activitiEvent.getProcessInstanceId(), groupId, "participant");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first try to check that your workflow is really started by access to "workflow I have started".  You should see your task in "active task" if not, that means there is some errors in your definitions. If everything is ok, check your group name and don’t forget to add "GROUP_"myGRPName.
If you want to see the workflow instances it’s simpler with web script and services.

Comment: I want to use a different user to access the process: the user that belongs to the candidate group

Comment: Can you give more details

Comment: The process is started by user X and has a parallel review withe multiple tasks. Each task has a "candidate group". I cannot see the process with user Y that belongs to one of the candidate group, I would expect to see the process.

Comment: There are two possible causes, your process did not start, or you assign tasks incorrectly. Can you give the definition.

Comment: the process started, I can see it using the user that started it (and you can see the records in table that I copied above). The task is assigned correctly: I can see it using user Y. What I cannot see is the process.